# RecyclerView - Is it correct to set a ClickableSpan Listener inside onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, clickablespan

Is it correct to set ClickableSpan listeners inside RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder? For viewHolder I would be to implement a View.OnClickListener inside the viewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   //set viewHolders
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Set on click listener
    }
}
```

However ClickableSpan is a class. But I am unsure if recreating a new clickable span each time in onBindViewHolder is the correct way to do it.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //holder.viewHolderUsername.setText(list.get(position).getPosted_by_user());
    holder.viewHolderMessage.setText(list.get(position).getMessage());

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(list.get(position).getPosted_by_user());

    String word = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPosted_by_user();
    final int startingPosition = word.indexOf(word);
    final int endingPosition = startingPosition + word.length();

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };


    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, startingPosition, endingPosition, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    holder.viewHolderUsername.setText(ss);
    holder.viewHolderUsername.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }
```

Comment: Well, since your click event source is dynamic, i.e. a single word of some dynamic text that is only known during binding, I don't see how else you could otherwise accomplish this. If this concerns you in any way you could probably "fake" it by just formatting the text word as clickable, but then react on clicks on the entire `viewHolderUsername` widget.